# Function minimization with error in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a function of the form: (y1,y2,y3)=x*(a1,a2,a3)+(b1,b2,b3), where x,y1,y2,y3 are measured values and a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 are parameters I want to fit for. I also have some measurement errors associated with x,y1,y2,y3. I would like to fit this function for a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3, and obtain an error on the values of each of these parameters, while taking into account the errors on x,y1,y2,y3. How can I do this? I looked into scipy and lmfit, but I didn't really find something that allows me to both pass the errors on the measured points and return the errors on the fitted parameters. Here is some code I have for the data I need to fit:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
err_x = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1])
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  y = y + [x[i]*np.array([3,4,5])+np.array([-2,3,1])]
y = np.array(y)
err_y = np.array([[0.2,0.2,0.1],[0.2,0.2,0.1],[0.2,0.2,0.1],[0.2,0.2,0.1],[0.2,0.2,0.1]])
```

Comment: Both lmfit and scipy.optimize can definitely be used with uncertainties in the data values, and return information about the best-fit values and the estimated uncertainties for the parameters.   Any further comment would almost certainly require a question with a minimal working example of code that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I didn't manage to pass errors on the independent variable in either of them

Comment: uncertainties in the independent data are not handled directly in lmfit.Model or scipy.optimize.curve_fit.   scipy.odr can handle these.  OTOH minimization, in general, has no concept of independent data, so you may be able to include the effect of those uncertainties if you treat all data values as being part of the model. But (again!), here at SO the emphasis is on code.  For follow-up responses, post code and ask questions about that code.

Comment: I added some code to show the data I have better. Does scipy.odr allow functions with multiple outputs, as in my case my output is a list, not a number?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html